# Open new window and then blur() or focus previous window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going crazy about a problem...

```
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                var main = $(document);
                var temp = $(window);
                console.log("JQuery works");
                var attributes = 'width=400,height=400,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbars=no';
                var newWindow = open('http://www.google.de','_blank',attributes);               
            });
```

I am calling this jQuery function and want the newly opened window "newWindow" to blur into the backgrround. Using

```
newWindow.blur();
```

doesnt work.

```
main.focus();

temp.focus();
```

also doesnt work.

In the end it doesnt matter if I blur the new window or focus the previous (where there is a button to call the function). I just want to create a "invisible" popup window in the background.

Comment: That could be browsers blocking pop-unders, which are just really annoying. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah that is what my teacher also said. Of course it is annoying :) but we got this as a assignment to somehow accomplish... it is possible he said. I found out that if I where to call alert() then the focus shifts back to my main window. is there a similiar function to alert() which doesnt popup as alert does?